# how to convert a floating point into a string

Tags: c++

How to convert a floating point into a string and add the 2 decimals when the floating point is a round number. Currently I am using the following, but for round numbers, I would like to have the .00 added. Do I need to write my own routine for that?

```
float floatingNumber = 1.00;
string string;
ostringstream stream;

stream << floatingNumber;
string += stream.str(); // result is 1 not 1.00
```

Comment: `float floatingNumber = 1.00;` is identical to `float floatingNumber = 1;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precise floating-point<->string conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311242/precise-floating-point-string-conversion)

Comment: @MadKeithV: Similar, but that is not the same issue. It deals with the (mathematically real) difference between 1.34 and 1.340000000001. This deals with the (mathematically non-existent) difference between 1 and 1.00.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set precision manually and use flag, that allows you to use `fixed notation`

[setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) [fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)

```
stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << floatingNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, howver my compiler says that setprecision is not a member of std. Is my compiler too old (borland c++ 6.0).

Comment: @MicheldeMan How about check links? `#include <iomanip>` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using c++11, you can convert a float to std::string using [std::to_string()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/)

```
float f(0.5f);
std::string str = std::to_string(f);
```

Same thing using auto :

```
auto f(0.5f); // f is a float
auto str = std::to_string(f); // str is a std::string
```

However, you'll have to handle the precision manually.